# How to use Python 3.6 interpreter inside a bash script?

Tags: python, linux, bash, coverage.py

I want to have a little script, that will find, run and report about all the tests in the folder, like this one:

```
#!/bin/bash 
coverage run -m unittest discover 
coverage report -m
```

But, when I run it, I get some errors, which I do not get on Windows (like using of `super()` without an argument). As I've understood, it's connected with the fact, that build-in and default version of Python on Linux is 2.x, whereas I am using 3.6. How should I change the script, so it would use Python 3.6 interpreter?

EDIT:
So here's one of the files with tests that I run:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import unittest
import random
import math
import sort_functions as s
from comparison_functions import less, greater


class BaseTestCases:
    class BaseTest(unittest.TestCase):
        sort_func = None

        def setUp(self):
            self.array_one = [101, -12, 99, 3, 2, 1]
            self.array_two = [random.random() for _ in range(100)]
            self.array_three = [random.random() for _ in range(500)]
            self.result_one = sorted(self.array_one)
            self.result_two = sorted(self.array_two)
            self.result_three = sorted(self.array_three)

        def tearDown(self):
            less.calls = 0
            greater.calls = 0

        def test_sort(self):
            result_one = self.sort_func(self.array_one)
            result_two = self.sort_func(self.array_two)
            result_three = self.sort_func(self.array_three)
            self.assertEqual(self.result_one, result_one)
            self.assertEqual(self.result_two, result_two)
            self.assertEqual(self.result_three, result_three)

    # and some more tests here       


class TestBubble(BaseTestCases.BaseTest):
    def setUp(self):
    self.sort_func = s.bubble_sort
    super().setUp()

# and some more classes looking like this
```

And the error:

```
ERROR: test_key (test_sort_func.TestBubble)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/lelik/Desktop/Sorters/test_sort_func.py", line 67, in setUp
super().setUp()
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, but you need to actually install Python3

Comment: @cricket_007 No, the script is `bash` (`coverage` is a script or binary which itself relies on a Python env), not `python`. What OP needs to find out is how it is configured, and why the configuration that (assumedly) work in his shell isn't there in his script.

Comment: @cricket_007, tried this, still get `TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`. Python3 is definitely installed

Comment: We can't see your code, but can you add it and the full traceback?

Comment: @OlgaGekkel You need provide more details to your [mcve] please.

Comment: @Aaron, yeah, the script is `bash`, and I need to get it work correctly with my files, written in Python 3.6

Comment: @OlgaGekkel Why don't you take the suggestion of the answer and use something like tox? It is made for this and will save you the hassle of all this stuff. I highly recommend tox. It is great. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tox

Comment: @cricket_007, done

Comment: @idjaw, details are now provided

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, install it for your python3 (if you have it and `pip` installed)
`sudo python3 -m pip install coverage`

Then, in order to run coverage for python3, run `python3 -m coverage report -m`

So your final script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
python3 -m coverage run -m unittest discover 
python3 -m coverage report -m
```

Also you can replace `python3` with path to your pythons bin. For example `/usr/bin/python3`. So You can call it this way as well:

```
#!/bin/bash 
/usr/bin/python3 -m coverage run -m unittest discover 
/usr/bin/python3 -m coverage report -m
```

Comment: Running `sudo` command gives me this error: `/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip`, but both `pip` and `coverage` are already installed, cause running `pip install coverage` tells me `Requirement already satisfied: coverage in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

Comment: You are missing `pip` for python3 :) Try `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`. Then you will be able to use `pip3` or `python3 -m pip`.

Comment: it turns out, I also can use a `coverage3` command, so it looks a little bit better, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `coverage` command on your Linux host has been installed for Python 2.  That is, somewhere there exists a `coverage` script that starts with:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

And on your system, `/usr/bin/python` is python 2.

The best solution here is probably to set up a Python 3 [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) for running your tests (and then installing `coverage` into that virtualenv).  You may also want to investigate [tox](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which will handle this for you automatically.